# ms-access: file already in use ERROR

Tags: ms-access

i have an access backend MDB

it is supporting multiple user connections

every user has their own access front end

for this one particular user (her permissions arent any different from other users) she is getting `FILE ALREADY IN USE` error when she tries to open this database using her front end

if you have any suggestions please let me know asap, as this is urgent for me

Comment: For clarity, please share a little more information on the following:
- Are you users connecting from different machines
- Are they using separate copies of the FrontEnd.mdb
- Are they using the same connection string
- What is the connection string(s) being used

Comment: @Sorax: I'm having a hard time figuring out how an Access app with a Jet back end (MDB) could use any connection string that would lead to access issues like this. Please explain what you're suggesting, as the norm here would be plain native Jet linked tables, i.e., without any special permissions or username/password issues.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Of course you're correct, linked tables are most likely being used here. I was just falling back to my experience with db connectivity and first asking baseline questions from which I would proceed. I recently used a Jet provider to connect with a spreadsheet and had to set the connection's "Mode" property for it to behave as needed. There's nothing stopping you from similarly setting Database properties in Access, although it would be unusual. We would have also gained knowledge if your response had come from jenny; ruling out the outlier and establishing her understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But are this users permissions for the BE Access database file folder different than the others?  Can that user create, update and delete a txt file using Notepad in the same folder as the BE?

Comment: That is, are all the users of the database members of the NTFS security group that is being used to grant permissions on the folder and share where the back end is stored?

Answer (score 1):

In her front-end, go into **Tools->Options->Advanced**. Change the default Open mode from **Exclusive** to **Shared**.