# Access the single MS Access database on multiple application with networking

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

```
OleDbConnection myCon;
public DataConclass( string username)
{
   myCon = new OleDbConnection(String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};", username));
   myCon.Open();        
}
```

Showing Error: 
File already in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772749/ms-access-file-already-in-use-error) SO question.

Comment: Please take it from me you will have nothing but headaches using access across the wire. You should look into using a real rdbms